# Convergence or divergence of a sequence - wrong result with logical steps.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

My result differs from more reliable sources ([Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com), and [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/)), but I'm unable to determine where I go wrong.

Given the sequence:
$$
s_n=\frac{2-n^3}{n^3+2n^2-5n+8}
$$

I divide numerator and denominator by $n^3$:

$$
s_n=\frac{
\frac{2}{n^3}-\frac{n^3}{n^3}}
{\frac{n^3}{n^3}+\frac{2n^2}{n^3}-\frac{5n}{n^3}+\frac{8}{n^3}}
$$

...simplifying...

$$
s_n=\frac{
\frac{2}{n^3}-1}
{1+\frac{2}{n}-\frac{5}{n^2}+\frac{8}{n^3}}
$$

Using the particular cases of behaviour of $n\to\infty$:

As ${n\to\infty}$, ${\frac{2}{n^3}\to 0}$

As ${n\to\infty}$, ${\frac{2}{n}\to 0}$

As ${n\to\infty}$, ${\frac{5}{n^2}\to 0}$

As ${n\to\infty}$, ${\frac{8}{n^3}\to 0}$

Applying these rules, $s_n = \frac{0-1}{1+0+0+0}$ $= -1$

...and I conclude the sequence converges (on $-1$).

Symbolab seems to have only a [Series Calculator](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/series-calculator)*, when [used for the sequence in question](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/series-convergence-calculator/%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cleft(2-n%5E%7B3%7D%5Cright)%2F%5Cleft(n%5E%7B3%7D%2B2n%5E%7B2%7D-5n%2B8%5Cright)), it states the series diverges.

*For some reason the link breaks in Microsoft Edge browser but works on Chrome.

Comment: Your result is correct. Either you didn't input correctly the data in WA or whatever, or those programs are high once again...

Comment: The SEQUENCE converges you are right, but the SERIES diverges as it doesnt tend to $0$.

Comment: your solution is right. https://www.symbolab.com/solver/series-convergence-calculator/%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft(%5Cleft(2-n%5E%7B3%7D%5Cright)%2F%5Cleft(n%5E%7B3%7D%2B2n%5E%7B2%7D-5n%2B8%5Cright)%5Cright)

Comment: I checked wolfram and it says the sequence convergence to -1 as $n$ goes to $\infty$. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+s_n%3D%5Cfrac%7B2-n%5E3%7D%7Bn%5E3%2B2n%5E2-5n%2B8%7D

Comment: Every step is correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no contradiction. The limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n$ is $-1$ and the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty s_n$ diverges.

Comment: Isn't $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n$ equal to $-1$, not $0$?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your **sequence** $s_n$ is convergent, but the **series** $\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}s_n$ is not, because of the limit of the sequence is not $0$. (If the $\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_n$ is convergent, then the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n$ must be $0$. But the sequence's limit doesn't guarentee the convergence of the series, like in the case of $\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N^+}} \frac{1}{n}$)